# having trouble with always block in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm currently making a watch that we can set times to start and having a problem with always@()

```
always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset or posedge sw3 or posedge sw4) begin
    if(reset == 1) begin //reset signal is not a pulse therefore this could do the thing needed for keep pressing the reset button
        tmp_second = 0;
        tmp_minute = 0;
        tmp_hour = 0;
    end
```

the above is just a part of the full code and the rest of it is about setting the time by sw3 and sw4 but when I try to Synthesize this module
the following Error comes up

```
ERROR:Xst:2089 - "first_mode.v" line 69: This sensitivity list construct will match none of the supported FF or Latch templates.
```

if I change the always block like

```
always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
```

I dont get the error message but I want posedge sw3 and sw4 to work independently from clk

would there be any way to use always block including those 4

Comment: You should think from hardware prospective for any type of HDL design. The hardware FlipFlops have one clock (edge sensitive) and one reset pin. However in your code, you have given multiple edge sensitive signals for the always block and that's why the synthesizer shows the error.

Better you first draw some rough hardware and then code according to that. Why do you need `posedge sw3` and `posedge sw4`, instead of just `sw3` and `sw4`?

Answer (score 2):

When synthesising, it is wise to be consistent by sticking to a template. Here is one such template for sequential logic with an asynchronous reset, which all synthesis tools should understand:

```
always @(posedge CLOCK  or posedge RESET)  // or negedge
  begin
    // PUT NO CODE HERE
    if (RESET == 1'b1)  // or (RESET == 1'b0) for an active-low reset
      // set the variables driven by this always block to their reset values
      // MAKE SURE YOU USE NON-BLOCKING ASSIGNMENTS ( <= )
    else
      // do things that occur on the rising (or falling) edge of CLOCK
      // stuff here gets synthesised to combinational logic on the D input
      // of the resulting flip-flops
      // MAKE SURE YOU USE NON-BLOCKING ASSIGNMENTS ( <= )
end
```

Here is the corresponding template for a sequential process without an asynchronous reset:

```
always @(posedge CLOCK)  // or negedge
  begin
    // do things that occur on the rising (or falling) edge of CLOCK
    // stuff here gets synthesised to combinational logic on the D input
    // of the resulting flip-flops
    // MAKE SURE YOU USE NON-BLOCKING ASSIGNMENTS ( <= )
end
```

And finally, here is the template for combinational logic:

```
always @(*)
  begin
    // implement your combinational logic here
    // MAKE SURE YOU USE BLOCKING ASSIGNMENTS ( = )
end
```

Your code does not comform to any of these three templates nor any other. That is why you synthesis tool doesn't understand it.