# Diffrence between simulation and synthesises of verilog always block

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have designed a simple counter. 
The code below.

```
input sig;
reg [3:0] cnt;
always @(sig) begin
    if(sig) 
        cnt = cnt + 1;
end
```

The Simulation with Modelsim works correctly. I implemented the code on fpga (Spartan 6 by ise 14.7) when sig is high the counter counts continuously!!!?
sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the simulation on Modelsim "works correctly", but do not specify how you are defining "correctly". I simulated it and nothing interesting happens at all: `cnt` remains at `4'bx` because you have no mechanism for initialising it. I would imagine that you are intending `cnt` to increment on every rising edge of `sig`. This occurs if you do initialise `cnt` (see the commented out code):

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4zXf

However, whilst this code can be synthesised, this is not a *synchronous* design, and so it synthesises to nonsense (an adder and four latches). Assuming you do require `cnt` to increment on every rising edge of `sig`, you need to increment this design *synchronously*:

```
always @(posedge sig)
    cnt <= cnt + 1;
```

This will synthesise to an adder and four D-type flip-flops.

It is normal to reset a counter, because otherwise in real hardware the counter will have an unknown value (hence the `4'bx` in the simulation). You can get away with initialising `cnt` in an FPGA:

```
reg [3:0] cnt = 4'b0;
```

but you might want to consider a reset signal instead:

```
always @(posedge sig, posedge reset)
  if(reset) 
    cnt <= 4'b0;  // or some other reset value
  else
      cnt <= cnt + 1;
```

I am troubled by your naming of `sig`; most people would call this `clk` or `clock` or something similar. This name suggests you're perhaps not familiar with *synchronous design*. If so, you should find out about that and should also read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260145/having-trouble-with-always-block-in-verilog/41263924#41263924).