# Why are my Verilog output registers only outputting "x"?

Tags: output, verilog

I've written the following module to take in a 12-bit stream of input, and run it through the [Exponential Moving Average (EMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) formula. When simulating the program, it appears as if my output is a 12-bit stream of "don't cares". Regardless of what my input is, it isn't realized by the output register.

I'm a beginner at Verilog, so I'm sure there are a slew of issues here, but I expected to at least get some kind of output. Why is this behavior occurring and how can I fix it from occurring in the future? I've linked a screenshot of my waveform results at the bottom of this post.

My verilog module:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module EMATesting (     input signed [11:0] signal_in,
                        output reg signed [11:0] signal_out,
                        input clock_in,
                        input reset,
                        input enable,
                        output reg [11:0] newEMA);

reg [11:0] prevEMA;
reg [11:0] y;
reg [11:0] temp;
integer count = 0;
integer t = 1;
integer one = 1;
integer alpha = 0.5;

always @(posedge clock_in) begin

    if (reset) begin
        count = 0;
        end

    else if (count < 64) begin
         count = count + 1;
        end

//set the output equal to the first value received
    if (count == 1) begin
        newEMA = signal_in;
        end

//if not the first value, run through the formula
    else begin
        temp = newEMA;
        prevEMA = temp;
        newEMA = alpha * signal_in + (one-alpha) * prevEMA;
        count = count + 1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

My verilog testbench:

```
`timescale 10ns / 1ns
module testbench_EMA;

reg signal_in;
reg clock_in, reset, enable;
wire [11:0] signal_out;
wire [11:0] newEMA;

initial begin
    signal_in = 0; reset = 0; enable = 0;
    clock_in = 0;
end

EMATesting DUT(signal_in, signal_out, clock_in, reset, enable, newEMA);

initial
begin
//test some values with timing intervals here 
#100;
reset = 1;
#100;
reset = 0;
enable = 1;
#100;
//set signal_in to "1" repeating 12 times
signal_in = { 12 { 1'b1}};
#100;
reset = 1;
#100; //buffer to end simulation
$finish;
end


always
    #5 clock_in = !clock_in;

endmodule
```

[Waveform results of my testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgjZP.jpg). Note that both output registers are giving no values.

Comment: You should probably move this question over to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, you'll probably have better luck there. Myself I'm not a Verilog user (VHDL instead), but I can point out three basic issues: 1) you never assign a value to `signal_out` anywhere, so that explains the X's there, 2) you should always reset all your outputs in the `reset` block, and 3) you are setting `alpha` to 0.5, but you have declared it as an `integer`, so that clearly won't work. It appears there are some Verilog assignment issues too, but again you'll need actual Verilog users to point those out.

Comment: I agree with @Mr. Snrub. Additionally,  NEVER use '=' - blocking assignment in always@(posedge clock_in) block.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260145/having-trouble-with-always-block-in-verilog/41263924#41263924).

Answer (score 2):

There are many mistakes in your code. @Mr. Snrub listed some of them. You can correct the mistakes that are listed in the comments, and by further editing your code you can make it work as you wish, **but there are more important fundamental problems**. You have to solve them before you make further and hard to debug mistakes in the future, it also gives advantage of understanding HDL concepts better.

- First of all, you need to understand the difference between software programming languages and hardware description languages. You should make further research for that, the mistakes you made are commonly made by developers who assume HDL is similar to software programming languages. Check [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132611/whats-the-motivation-in-using-verilog-or-vhdl-over-c) link for further information.
- You need to further understand how the Verilog HDL (or any other HDL) codes are synthesized and why they are used.
- Need to be familiar when and how to use blocking `=` or non-blocking `<=` assignments and how they work. Check [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/difference-between-blocking-and-nonblocking-assignment-verilog) link.

When you research about the listed topics, you will understand that in edge sensitive (synchronous or sequential) `always` block, it is bad idea to use blocking `=` assignment.

When you use blocking assignment, the assignments are done in series, as in common software programming languages. In the case of edge sensitive `always` block, you have very limited time to finish all required assignments inside the `always` block.

In your case, as all the assignments inside the edge sensitive always block are blocking (assuming no reset condition):

- First, it checks if `count` is less than 64, and completes the assignment if that is the case. All other assignments are waiting for that assignment to finish.
- By the time the first assignment is done, the `always` block with `posedge clock_in` sensitivity might have ended execution and waiting for the next edge of the clock. So, other assignments are not done.
- As you have not initialized your output registers, they initially were filled with 'don't cares' and new value is never assigned again, so, as a result, you got that output (filled with 'don't cares').
- Even when `count` becomes larger than or equal to 64, you have other blocking assignments before you assign value to `newEMA`.