# can the @(posedge clk) be synthesized?

Tags: verilog

Can the following code be synthesized? In the code, the @posedge is used, not always @posedge. Can it be synthesized? If so, what will be the circuits?

THanks,

Brian

```
  module state_machine(clk,reset,read,data_out);

  ......

  always @(reset or read)
    begin
    @(posedge clk)
    if(reset) p<=0;
    elseif(read)
    begin
     data_out<=ram_data[p];
    @(posedge clk)
   p<=p+1;
   end
 endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You mean I can try to synthesize it and it will not  be able to? What will be the warning message? I will give it a try later. Thank you very much, Brian

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260145/having-trouble-with-always-block-in-verilog/41263924#41263924).

Comment: Hi Matthew and Oldfart Thanks a lot for your comments. I tried it and it reports the following errors.              @(posedge clk)
             |
Error   : Unsynthesizable construct. [VLOGPT-34] [read_hdl]
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Hi all It is also not allow to have one always inside another always statement, right?   The following module does not work at all. Do I miss anything?                                                                                                                                  module state_machine(clk,reset,read,data_out);
   
   input clk, reset,read;
   output data_out;
   
   always @(reset or read)
     begin
 always @(posedge clk)
   begin
   end
     end
   
endmodule

Comment: No it's not allowed either. You probably want to use `if` statements inside the `always @(posedge clk)` instead. I'd also look at some example synthesisable Verilog (eg open source cores etc) to get an idea of how it is usually written

Comment: Hi David How to use if statement inside the always statement to make it happen?

Comment: BTW, #10, this is not synthesizable as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly trying to create a state machine, which is a fully supported thing to build in Verilog. Its just that they way you are coding is not the clearest way to do this, in terms of other people understanding your code, and also very important, the synthesis and implementation tools implementing precisely what you are seeking.

You ask if I would I be more precise about what is bad or ambiguous with they way the design is currently coded?  Sure. The statement @(posedge clk); used in line says to stop the execution of the current code until the clock goes from low to high, after the previous statements were executed.  In a simulator, or c program, it is posible to do this; you would suspend the process that is implementing that always block.  Further the tool would (some how) arrange that the code is no longer activated it when an event in the original sensitivity list "always @(read or rst)" occurs; but now resume the process when the event posedge clock occurs.

For the synthesis tool to implement this, it would have to build logic that sometimes looks for read and rst, and other times looks for a change of clock from 0 to 1; and keep track of when to do which activity. Or restated, it would have to create a state machine to implement your coding style (which is then creating another state machine!). While all things are possible, a tradeoff was made.

The original authors of synthesis tools met with the original coders of Verilog simulators and designers of logic and worked out a deal (IEEE Std 1364.1 - Verilog Register Transfer Level Synthesis) to define what constructs would be easy for humans to code, efficient for the simulators to execute, and straightforward for the synthesis tools to build logic that executed exactly the way the simulators executed.

Following this lead, it is far better for you to describe the state machine you want in a way that has clear hardware implementation methodology.

A state machine has construct that maintains a register that hold the value of the current state, and then separately logic that calculates the value of the next state, based on the current state, and the inputs to the module.  (See Mealy machine in the literature, such as Wikipedia, alternatively see the Moore Machine)

Based on looking at your code, a typical Mealy state machine would be:

```
module sm (/*AUTOARG*/
   // Outputs
   data,
   // Inputs
   address, clk, read, rst
   ) ;
   input clk;
   input rst;
   input read;
   input [8:0] address
   output [31:0] data;
   reg [31:0] mem[256]

   // State registers for state
   reg [2:0] state, next_state;
   parameter idle_state = 0, read_state = 1;

   // State FF for state
   always @ ( posedge clk or rst ) begin
      if ( rst ) state = idle_state; else
        state = next_state;
   end

   // Next State Logic for state
   always @ ( /*AUTOSENSE*/ /*memory or*/ addr_in or idle_state
             or read or read_state or state) begin
      case (state) 
        idle_state: begin
           if (read) begin
              address    = addr_in;
              next_state = read_state;
           end
        end
        read_state: begin
           data = mem[address];
           next_state = idle_state;
        end
      endcase // case (cmd)
   end // always @ (...
endmodule // sm
```

Comment: Thanks Mac for showing me how to neatly code. BTW, the for loop is not synthesizable, right?

Answer (score 0):

````````````````
module state_machine(clk,reset,read,data_out);

  ......

  always @(reset or read)
    begin
    @(posedge clk)  // No @ allowed inside another @
    if(reset) p<=0; // reset data_out also .
    elseif(read)
    begin
     data_out<=ram_data[p];
    @(posedge clk)  // No @ inside another @
   p<=p+1;
   end
 endmodule

``````````````

Not clear about the intend here but the closest i could write to the code was...
This will keep on increment the address and output its content everytime there is a read pulse. 
Assuming memory already has data from a different logic.(write to memory)
Assuming p width is takes care of the depth of the memory.

```````````````
module state_machine(clk,reset,read,data_out);

  ......

  always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
    begin
    if(~reset) 
    begin
      p<=0;
      data_out<=0;
    else begin
      if(read)
       begin
         data_out<=ram_data[p];
         p<=p+1;
       end
 endmodule

`````````````
````````````````

Comment: Please give more context arround your code. Explay what was wrong with the code in the question and what did you changed to improve it.